# CTRL S Function adds an s if the cursor is left in an input field, how do you stop it?

Tags: javascript, dom

The code that I am using below works fine, except for the fact that it adds an 's' if the cursor is left in an input field. How do I do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> without having that pesky s being added?

```
window.onload = function() {

//-------------------------------------------------------------------->>
// CTRL-S FEATURE:
//-------------------------------------------------------------------->>
var isCtrl = false; 
document.attachEvent('onkeyup', KeyUpHandler); 
document.attachEvent('onkeydown', KeyDownHandler); 

function KeyUpHandler() {
    if (event.keyCode == 17) { 
    isCtrl = false; 
    }
}//end of function 

function KeyDownHandler() {
    if (event.keyCode == 17) { isCtrl = true }
    if (event.keyCode == 83 && isCtrl == true) {
    v8_update()
    } 
}//end of function

}//end of onload()
```

Much thanks and appreciation for all your help and support in advance,

Cheers

Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keydown` handler should prevent the default action from continuing -- i.e. the character being inserted into the focused element. To accomplish this, use the `preventDefault` method of the event object:

```
function KeyDownHandler(evnt) {
    var evnt = evnt || window.event;
    if (evnt.keyCode == 83 && evnt.ctrlKey) {
        evnt.preventDefault ? evnt.preventDefault() : window.event.returnValue = false;
        v8_update();
        return false;
    }
}
```

On can also return false to stop propagation AND prevent default, however, this may be detrimental to other events that are bound to the same element as your event -- you may desire propagation, especially when attaching such an event to the document itself. If so, take out the false return.

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/LzezS/

**Documentation**

- event.preventDefault on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:event.preventDefault
- DOM event specification on W3 - http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-preventDefault
- MSDN and IE's non-standard event model - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- event.ctrlKey on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.ctrlKey

Comment: Note that the OP uses `attachEvent` = IE8-. So, no `preventDefault()`.

Comment: Duly noted -- added IE support.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use such a hack to detect whether `ctrl` is pressed or not. Simply check the boolean [`event.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.ctrlKey) property. Another thing, your code will only work in ancient IE browsers, because of the use of [`attachEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent). This should be your code:

```
function keyDownHandler(event) {
    event = event || window.event; // <-- IE
    if (event.keyCode == 83 && event.ctrlKey) {
        v8_update();
        return false; // <--
    } 
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler, false);
} else {
    document.attachEvent('onkeydown', keyDownHandler);
}
```

`return false;` stops the propagation of the event, and prevents the character from being entered: http://jsfiddle.net/ZwejW/.